# Corrupted docx generated using zipping

Tags: java, android, zip, docx

Let me just start out by saying I created an account on here because I've been beating my head against a wall in order to try and figure this out, so here it goes.

Also, I have already seen this question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566468/how-to-compress-a-folder-to-make-docx-file-in-android) Neither one of those answers have helped and I have tried both of them.

I need to create a word document with a simple table and data inside. I decided to create a sample document in which to get the xml that I need to create the document. I moved all the folders from the unzipped docx file into my assets folder. Once I realized I couldn't write to the assets folder, I wrote a method to copy all the files and folders over to an external storage location of the device and then write the document I created to the same location. From there Im trying to zip the files back up to a .docx file. This is where things arent working.

The actual docx file is created and I can move it to my computer through the DDMS but when I go to view it Word says its corrupt. Heres whats weird though, if I unzip it and then rezip it on my computer without making any changes what so ever it works perfectly. I have used a program (for mac) called DiffMerge to compare the sample unzipped docx file to the unzipped docx that I have created and it says they are exactly the same. So, **I think it has something to do with the zipping process in Android**.

I have also tried unzipping the sample docx file on my computer, moving all the files and folders over to my assets folder including the document.xml file and just try to zip it up without adding my own document.xml file and using the sample one and that doesnt work either. Another thing I tried was to place the actual docx file in my assets folder, unzipping it onto my external storage and then rezipping it without doing anything. This also fails.

I'm basically at a loss. Please somebody help me figure this out.

Here is some of my code:

1. moveDocxFoldersFromAssetsToExternalStorage() is called first.
2. After that is called all the files have been moved over.
3. Then, I create the document.xml file and place it in the word directory where it belongs
4. Everything is where it should be and I now try to create the zip file.

.

```
private boolean moveDocxFoldersFromAssetsToExternalStorage(){
    File rootDir = new File(this.externalPath);
    rootDir.mkdir();

    copy("");

    // This is to get around a glitch in Android which doesnt list files or folders
    // with an underscore at the beginning of the name in the assets folder.
    // This renames them once they are saved to the device.
    // We need it to show up in the list in order to move them.

    File relsDir = new File(this.externalPath + "/word/rels");
    File renameDir = new File(this.externalPath + "/word/_rels");
    relsDir.renameTo(renameDir);

    relsDir = new File(this.externalPath + "/rels");
    renameDir = new File(this.externalPath + "/_rels");
    relsDir.renameTo(renameDir);

    // This is to get around a glitch in Android which doesnt list hidden files.
    // We need it to show up in the list in order to move it.

    relsDir = new File(this.externalPath + "/_rels/rels.rename");
    renameDir = new File(this.externalPath + "/_rels/.rels");
    relsDir.renameTo(renameDir);

    return true;
}

private void copy(String outFileRelativePath){
    String files[] = null;
    try {
        files = this.mAssetManager.list(ASSETS_RELATIVE_PATH + outFileRelativePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String assetFilePath = null;
    for(String fileName : files){
        if(!fileName.contains(".")){
            String outFile = outFileRelativePath + java.io.File.separator + fileName;
            copy(outFile);
        } else {
            File createFile = new File(this.externalPath + java.io.File.separator + outFileRelativePath);
            createFile.mkdir();
            File file = new File(createFile, fileName);

            assetFilePath = 
                ASSETS_RELATIVE_PATH + outFileRelativePath + java.io.File.separator + fileName;

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = this.mAssetManager.open(assetFilePath);
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

private void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String destZipFile) throws Exception{
    FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(destZipFile);
    ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);
    zip.setMethod(Deflater.DEFLATED);
    zip.setLevel(ZipOutputStream.STORED);

    addFolderToZip(this.externalPath, "", zip);

    zip.finish();
    zip.close();
}


private void addFolderToZip(String externalPath, String folder, ZipOutputStream zip){
    File file = new File(externalPath);
    String files[] = file.list();

    for(String fileName : files){
        try {
            File currentFile = new File(externalPath, fileName);
            if(currentFile.isDirectory()){
                String outFile = externalPath + java.io.File.separator + fileName;          
                addFolderToZip(outFile, folder + java.io.File.separator + fileName, zip);
            } else {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
                int len;
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder + java.io.File.separator + fileName));
                while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    zip.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                zip.closeEntry();
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

Here is the code I wrote in order to get it working correctly based on what @edi9999 said below. I created a separate class that Im going to expand and add to and probably clean up a bit but this is working code. It adds all the files in a directory to the zip file and recursively calls itself to add all the subfiles and folders.

```
private class Zip {
    private ZipOutputStream mZipOutputStream;
    private String pathToZipDestination;
    private String pathToFilesToZip;

    public Zip(String pathToZipDestination, String pathToFilesToZip) {
        this.pathToZipDestination = pathToZipDestination;
        this.pathToFilesToZip = pathToFilesToZip;
    }

    public void zipFiles() throws Exception{
        FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(pathToZipDestination);
        this.mZipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter);
        this.mZipOutputStream.setMethod(Deflater.DEFLATED);
        this.mZipOutputStream.setLevel(8);

        AddFilesToZip("");

        this.mZipOutputStream.finish();
        this.mZipOutputStream.close();
    }

    private void AddFilesToZip(String folder){
        File mFile = new File(pathToFilesToZip + java.io.File.separator + folder);
        String mFiles[] = mFile.list();

        for(String fileName : mFiles){
            File currentFile;
            if(folder != "")
                currentFile = new File(pathToFilesToZip, folder + java.io.File.separator + fileName);
            else
                currentFile = new File(pathToFilesToZip, fileName);
            if(currentFile.isDirectory()){
                if(folder != "")
                    AddFilesToZip(folder + java.io.File.separator + currentFile.getName());
                else
                    AddFilesToZip(currentFile.getName());
            } else {
                try{
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
                    int len;
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
                    if(folder != ""){
                        mZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder + java.io.File.separator + fileName));
                    } else {
                        mZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
                    }
                    while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                        mZipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    mZipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is they any description on your error message when you load your doc ? If not, it is highly likely that word can't open this kind of zip file.

Comment: It says "This file is corrupt and can not be opened." Word is able to open the file though if I unzip it and then rezip it on my computer. Then it works just fine. It seems like theres something going on in the zipping process in Android that is making it so word cant unzip it.

Comment: The only problem I can think of is the compression method. I use jszip-inflate.js for zipping the file for docxgen.js : Demo: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/simpleTagging.html#
Repo https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs Also, you should know that you shouldn't zip the folder that contains the files, but the files themselves.

Comment: Could you please send the zip of the corrupted file ?

Comment: I know that there cant be a folder at the root of the zip. I found that out the hard way though. Here is my corrupted [File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30994479/Inspection.docx) Im not sure how I would adapt that code you linked to as java code for my Android app. I tried looking online to find out if there was any other ways of creating a zip on Android but could not find any variations.

Comment: Also, I did find this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039079/cannot-extract-file-from-zip-archive-created-on-android-device-os-specific) about some issue with compression on Android but implementing this didnt work either.

Comment: I need to zip .docx files after editing but then in PHP instead of Java. Has somebody this code in PHP maybe available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've got what's wrong.

When I opened your [corrupted File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30994479/Inspection.docx), and opened it on winrar, I saw antislashes at the beginning of the folders, which is unusual:

[image: Content of the corrupted Zip]

When I rezip the file after unzipping it, the antislashes are not there anymore and the file opens in Word so I think it should be the issue.

[image: Content of the corrected Zip]

I think the code is wrong here:

```
String outFile = externalPath + java.io.File.separator + fileName;
```

should be

```
if (externalPath=="")
    String outFile = externalPath + fileName;  
else 
    String outFile = externalPath + java.io.File.separator + fileName;
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! You are a freaking genius! Thank you so much. I guess thats what I get not using my pc when programming. All the zip extractors I used on mac never showed me that information. I finally got it to work by doing like you said but I had to tweak the code a little bit. Ill edit my post above to add the code. Thanks again!