# Create xlsx archive using xml files

Tags: java, xml, xlsx

With a java programm i unzipped an xlsx file and i made my modifications to xml files in it.

If i compress the files with S.O commands and rename with .xlsx instead of .zip, i can read the file with LibreOffice.

If i compress the same files with a java programm, LibreOffice tells that the file is corrupted.

(If i unzip the second zip archive and i zip it with S.O. commands it works).

Can it be some issue related to method compression? I can i solve?

Thanks

Comment: How did you compressed these files with java? Could you provide us some code?

Comment: Could you also provide a link to the zip that you created. I once answered a similar question, problem with the compression for docx documents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995397/how-to-create-a-docx-file-in-android/17039126#17039126